# Trying to send zip or Excel files on SFTP using Lambda from S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and Lambda and trying to copy S3 object like zip or Excel(txt/csv working) files from S3 bucket on S3 trigger and need to send those files on SFTP server. But the issue is when zip or excel files when received on SFTP server not getting open and showing corrupted. Same function working on Onprem environment.

Code I am trying is below, Can someone help me how to convert Zip/Excel files in correct stream and SFTP.

```
        var s3Event = evnt.Records?[0].S3;
        if (s3Event == null)
        {
            return "NoBucketFound";
        }
        try
        {
            String[] k = s3Event.Object.Key.Split("/");
            GetObjectResponse response = new GetObjectResponse();
            
            response = await this.S3Client.GetObjectAsync(s3Event.Bucket.Name, s3Event.Object.Key);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream);
            
            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // convert string to stream
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(content);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
           Console.Write("Hi...this is a Content of files : " + content);
            using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient("sftpserver",22, "Test", "test"))
            {
                sftp.Connect();
                if (sftp.IsConnected)
                {
                    try
                    {                                
                            sftp.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
                            sftp.UploadFile(stream, "/"+ s3Event.Object.Key.ToString(), true, null);
                            stream.Dispose();
                            Console.Write("SFTP RUN" + s3Event.Object.Key);
                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception exp)
                    {
                        Console.Write(exp.Message);
                    }
                }
                sftp.Disconnect();
            }

            return response.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Error getting object {s3Event.Object.Key} from bucket {s3Event.Bucket.Name}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.");
            context.Logger.LogLine(e.Message);
            context.Logger.LogLine(e.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: How are the files corrupted?, have you compared the file you are sending and the file you are receiving? and how do they differ? That might give you a clue as to the issue.

Comment: I think you can directly pass the `response.ResponseStream` into `sftp.FileUpload` method. `Encoding.Default` is dangerous as it is taken from the system defaults. Which may differ between environments.

Comment: Yes, I have compared all property & size r same, but when trying to unzip it show corrupted.

Comment: I have tried passing  response.ResponseStream, but this also not worked.

Comment: Still I am struggling, any help on this?